# Am i missing packages ? - After removing Wine 1.9.5 - removed packages - help

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, uninstall

I have been using Ubuntu for a while now.
Yesterday I tried to install WINE 1.9.5.

For some reason it didn't show up in the Dash so I tried to uninstall it
as instructed in the terminal: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:wine/wine-builds`

I noticed it started to uninstall/remove applications-packages I
hadn't even installed, although i'm not quite sure about a few packages
(so I cancelled it halfway through the process) and my **Question** is:

***1: why did it remove/uninstall packages like (for example: extremetux-data) when i don't have it installed ?***

***2: did it actually removed some packages i needed who were installed in the basic setup or atleast before i installed WINE like: (pandoc, pandoc-data or tcl) ?***

-

**HERE'S THE TERMINAL LOG and WHAT PACKAGES IT TRIED TO REMOVE (before i cancelled it):**

```
Removing kde-l10n-ja (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing ibus-anthy (1.5.4-2) ...
Removing anthy (9100h-23ubuntu2) ...
Removing anthy-common (9100h-23ubuntu2) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-ca (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-cs (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-da (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-de (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-fr (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-hu (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-it (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-nb (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-nl (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-pl (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-pt (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-ptbr (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-ru (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-sv (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-uk (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing calligra-l10n-zhtw (1:2.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing extremetuxracer-data (0.4-5ubuntu1) ...
Removing extremetuxracer-extras (0.6-1) ...
Removing fonts-inconsolata (001.010-5) ...
Removing gnome-web-photo (0.10.6-1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-zhtw (4:4.12.97-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing ibus-chewing (1.4.10.1-1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-ko (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing ibus-hangul (1.4.2-3) ...
Removing kde-l10n-bg (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-ca (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-cs (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-da (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-de (4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-engb (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-fr (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-hu (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-id (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-it (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-nb (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-nl (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-pl (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-pt (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-ptbr (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-ru (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-sv (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-th (4:4.10.97-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-uk (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing kde-l10n-vi (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libanthy0:amd64 (9100h-23ubuntu2) ...
Removing libchewing3:amd64 (0.3.5-4build1) ...
Removing libchewing3-data:amd64 (0.3.5-4build1) ...
Removing libhangul1:amd64 (0.1.0-3) ...
Removing libhangul-data (0.1.0-3) ...
Removing pandoc (1.12.2.1-1build2) ...
Removing liblua5.1-0:amd64 (5.1.5-5ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libmozjs185-1.0 (1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing tcl8.5 (8.5.15-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing libtcl8.5:amd64 (8.5.15-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing libtimezonemap1 (0.4.1) ...
Removing pandoc-data (1.12.2.1-1build2) ...
Removing python3-regex (0.1.20140216-1) ...
Removing python-regex (0.1.20140216-1) ...
Removing python3-enchant (1.6.5-2build1) ...
Removing python3-levenshtein (0.11.2-1build1) ...
Removing sbsigntool (0.6-0ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
```

**im very pleased with ubuntu and my system is very stable
thats why i want to know if i messed something up or accindentally uninstalled packages! (i am running the Gnome desktop enviroment ofcourse)**

Hopefully somebody can give me some more information about this?

Answer (score 0):

Many packages have other packages they depend on to work, (aptly) called "dependencies." These are installed automatically, the only reaction from the user being to confirm the install for the base package. The packages you see marked for removal are these dependencies.

The `ppa-purge` command deletes the specified repository (WINE's in this case), any installed packages available from it and any dependencies for these packages.

Run `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` before running the `ppa-purge` command again. Then run `sudo apt-get install -f` to make sure everything's OK.

***EDIT***: I just noticed there are a few system packages that you have already removed. The PPA Purge option may not be a good one. Instead, try running `sudo apt-get install -f` and then `sudo apt-get remove wine-*`.

Comment: @zacheree1 thankyou for your answer! i think i solved it but im new to this forum. i couldn't describe my solution and question in  just a few words so i commented BELOW as answer instead of comment

Answer (score 0):

@Zacharee1

**(SOLVED)**

**thankyou** very much for taking the time to explain.
ofcourse! i don't know why i haven't thought about its dependencies
but then again i still don't fully understand why packages(dependencies) like 
for example: (languagepackages) kde-l10n's ,or calligra-l10n etc.
have to do anything with WINE, removing WINE or Wine's repository ?

luckily i solved it, but with a diffrent approach. 
(since this accident occured on my laptop)

- i uninstalled it with a diffrent tutorial, then installed it
  and uninstalled it AGAIN, making sure it was completely removed!
- i have another PC with exactly the same ubuntu version
  and exactly the same programs installed (without WINE ofcourse) very stable.
  so i opened SYNAPTIC PACKAGE MANAGER and compared all the packages
  it removed when i accidentally used the ppa:purge command.
- thankgod it where only a few packages(65) to compare and i noticed
  everything was the same, none of the packages that were Removed on my laptop
  were installed on my PC! except for only 3 packages:
  sbsigntool (0.6-0ubuntu7)
  libtimezonemap1 (0.4.1)
  libmozjs185-1.0 (1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-4ubuntu1)
- I installed those 3 packages! but with or without those packages 
  i luckily havent experienced anything Missing yet or noticed instability
  whatsoever!*

**I SUPPOSE THIS SHOULD SOLVE THE WHOLE PROBLEM I HAD, FINDING OUT
IF I WAS MISSING ANYTHING OR MESSED SOMETHING UP IN UBUNTU,
OR IS THIS A WRONG SOLUTION/APPROACH AND DID I FORGET SOMETHING ??**